# Serializing complex properties without using Attributes

Tags: protobuf-net

I have a project in which I cannot use serialization attributes on the types I want to serialize.  Generally speaking I have it working by doing this:

```
private byte[] Serialize(object value)
{
    var type = value.GetType();
    var typeModel = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(type, false);

    foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        typeModel.Add(prop.Name);
    }

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        try
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(stream, value);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

However I have one type, `DynamicEntity` (see below), which is critical to the entire solution that won't serialize.  I've been working on it a bit, but I can't figure out a way to get the RuntimeTypeModel to hold the right info for serialization.  Instead Serialize keeps throwing an InvalidCastException with the message

> > "Unable to cast object of type 'OpenNETCF.ORM.FieldValue' to type 'System.String'."

Here are the relevant class definitions:

```
public class DynamicEntity
{
    public DynamicEntity();

    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public FieldCollection Fields { get; }
}

public class FieldCollection : IEnumerable<FieldValue>, IEnumerable
{
    public int Count { get; }

    public object this[string fieldName] { get; set; }

    public void Add(string fieldName);
    public void Add(string fieldName, object value);
    public IEnumerator<FieldValue> GetEnumerator();
}

public class FieldValue
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

FieldValue, generally, only holds simple values - things that a database field might hold. I *am* able to modify the definitions of the classes above (i.e. I own them), but I don't want to force other consumers of the type to in turn have to reference or use protobuf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the end it certainly wasn't as straightforward as I had hoped, and it's not as robust as I'd like since I've had to hard-code in the types that will work but the solution I'm working with has a finite set of types (right now anyway) so this bit of encapsulation wackiness, with indirect help from Marc, worked:

```
[ProtoContract]
internal class SerializableDynamicEntity
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string EntityName { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public List<SerializableFieldValue> Fields { get; set; }

    public SerializableDynamicEntity()
    {
        Fields = new List<SerializableFieldValue>();
    }

    private SerializableDynamicEntity(string name)
        : this()
    {
        EntityName = name;
    }

    public static explicit operator SerializableDynamicEntity(DynamicEntity de)
    {
        var sde = new SerializableDynamicEntity(de.EntityName);

        foreach (var f in de.Fields)
        {
            sde.Fields.Add(SerializableFieldValue.Create(f));
        }

        return sde;
    }

    public static explicit operator DynamicEntity(SerializableDynamicEntity sde)
    {
        var de = new DynamicEntity(sde.EntityName);

        foreach (var f in sde.Fields)
        {
            de.Fields.Add(f.Name, f.UntypedValue);
        }

        return de;
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(SerializableFieldValue<bool>))]
[ProtoInclude(4, typeof(SerializableFieldValue<int>))]
[ProtoInclude(5, typeof(SerializableFieldValue<double>))]
[ProtoInclude(6, typeof(SerializableFieldValue<string>))]
[ProtoInclude(7, typeof(SerializableFieldValue<DateTime>))]
[ProtoInclude(8, typeof(SerializableFieldValue<long>))]
[ProtoInclude(9, typeof(SerializableFieldValue<short>))]
internal abstract class SerializableFieldValue
{
    public static SerializableFieldValue<T> Create<T>(string name, T value)
    {
        return new SerializableFieldValue<T>()
        {
            Name = name,
            Value = value
        };
    }

    public static SerializableFieldValue Create(FieldValue f)
    {
        var type = f.Value.GetType();

        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(type))
        {
            case TypeCode.Boolean:
                return Create(f.Name, (bool)f.Value);
            case TypeCode.Int32:
                return Create(f.Name, (int)f.Value);
            case TypeCode.Double:
                return Create(f.Name, (double)f.Value);
            case TypeCode.String:
                return Create(f.Name, (string)f.Value);
            case TypeCode.DateTime:
                return Create(f.Name, (DateTime)f.Value);
            case TypeCode.Int64:
                return Create(f.Name, (long)f.Value);
            case TypeCode.Int16:
                return Create(f.Name, (short)f.Value);
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract object UntypedValue { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
internal sealed class SerializableFieldValue<T> : SerializableFieldValue
{
    public SerializableFieldValue()
    {
    }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public override object UntypedValue
    {
        get { return Value; }
        set { Value = (T)value; }
    }
}
```

This way the original base code doesn't need attributes or really even any changes, but the specific store implementation that needs serialization can hide this internally.

Comment: That's actually very clever. Nicely played.

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf-net doesn't like `object` much - it wants to understand the schema. One option here would be to have FieldValue as abstract with a generic subclass `FieldValue<T>`, explicitly providing a different subclass identifier. This can be done via `[ProtoInclude]` or via `RuntimeTypeModel`. It is not, however, obvious to me what the issue with consumers is here, i.e. whether attributes are an issue. Could you perhaps clarify?

Comment: The challenge is that this is in a generic, extendable ORM.  The types that can be stored into a FieldValue could be anything the implementer wants to store or retrieve for any imaginable store.  I'm currently implementing a cloud-backed store that doesn't lend itself to storing logical "rows", yet I need temporal consistency, so I'm storing a serialized entity.  The entity itself, however, is generated at run time by the user through a drag-and-drop UI.  And to make it more fun, the types coming from that, while currently static, needs to remain extensible to any type that might come up.

Comment: @ctacke I'll be honest: it doesn't sound like something that lends itself to protobuf-net

Comment: Thanks. This, along with a blog post I found, put me on the right track. You said that protobuf-net doesn't lend itself to this, but it's sure better than me hand-rolling some brittle, proprietary serializer.